# Showing and hiding a div with JS/jQuery in a Wordpress loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress

I am looking for some help using JS or jQuery to show and hide a div. This I am familiar with but the issue arrises while using this in a Wordpress loop. I have done this before but it was in a bit of a hack-y way and I thought I would try and find the correct way.

This is loop code:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8 ">
        <img src="WP IMAGE HERE" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 offers">
            <h2 class="offers--title">WP TITLE HERE</h2>
            <hr class="offers--hr">
            <p class="offers--bio">WP OFFER INFO HERE</p>
        <button type="button" href="#" onclick="showHide()" class="btn btn-crs-sm ">Redeem this offer</button>
        <div id="voucher"> THIS IS THE DIV TO BE SHOWN/HIDDEN</div>
    </div> 
</div>
```

My general plan of action was this:

Add an onclick to the button code that is in the loop:

```
<button type="button" href="#" onclick="showHide()" class="btn btn-crs-sm ">Redeem this offer</button>
```

show/hide using this code:

```
function showHide() {
    var x = document.getElementById("voucher");
    if (x.style.display === "none") {
        x.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        x.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

I then used:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("div[id^='vouche']").each(function(i) {
        $(this).attr('id', "voucher" + (i + 1));
    });
});
```

to add a number to the end of each ID called "voucher"

I then duplicated the first batch of code shown above three times to be called showHide1, 2 & 3 and refer to the div elements voucher1, 2 & 3.

The next issue is to then alter the code of the onclick in the buttons in the loop (so it says showHide1,2,3() etc.) – I tried to do this in jQuery but this was where I came unstuck and decided to look for help.

There must be a much easier & more efficient way of doing this!

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

## EDIT/UPDATE:

I have now edited my jQuery to this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("div[id^='vouche']").each(function(i) {
        $(this).attr('id', "voucher" + (i + 1));
    });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("button[id^='voucherButto']").each(function(i) {
        $(this).attr('id', "voucherButton" + (i + 1));
    });
});

$( "#voucherButton1" ).click(function() {
    $( "#voucher1" ).toggle( "slow", function() {
    });
});

$( "#voucherButton2" ).click(function() {
    $( "#voucher2" ).toggle( "slow", function() {
    });
});

$( "#voucherButton3" ).click(function() {
    $( "#voucher3" ).toggle( "slow", function() {
    });
});
```

This works correct as expected (adding the right numbers to the right Id's, etc) however it doesn't show/and hide correctly. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you please show your HTML code and actual output? Also what exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I have done now Smit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get elements with jQuery by `$('#yourId')`. jQuery has already a method which allows you to display or hide an element by just calling `toggle()`
 as described in their [docs](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/).

Your `showHide()` function can be replaced by this:

```
function showHide(yourPostId) {
  $('#voucher-' + yourPostId).toggle();
}
```

You have to extend each loop with an attribute that is related to the current iteration. For example with the post id...:

```
<?php while (have_posts()): ?>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8 ">
        <img src="WP IMAGE HERE" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 offers">
            <h2 class="offers--title">WP TITLE HERE</h2>
            <hr class="offers--hr">
            <p class="offers--bio">WP OFFER INFO HERE</p>
        <button type="button" href="#" onclick="showHide(<?php the_ID(); ?>)" class="btn btn-crs-sm ">Redeem this offer</button>
        <div id="voucher-<?php the_ID(); ?>"> THIS IS THE DIV TO BE SHOWN/HIDDEN</div>
    </div> 
  </div> 

<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: Hi, I am aware of this. How does this help with the area of the question that I am actually struggling with though? I'm not saying it doesn't but it's not very clear

Comment: I have implemented this code now, and it has made things a lot cleaner. I have edited the main post to reflect this.

Comment: Amazing! You are the man. Is there a jQuery way to make these div's hidden by default? I have set them as display:none; in CSS for now

Comment: Don't think so because jQuery is a javascript library. You do it right with the css in my opinion :)

Comment: Thanks again for your help!